# How to make KDE desktop works like MacOS

Tags: macos, desktop-environment, touchpad

I'm a Linux user for more than 20 years, but recently I need to work on Mac far more than on Linux. The less I need to work on Linux, the more I want my Linux desktop to work like mac.

I've done some research,

- there is a most recent one *"5 Linux Distributions That are Inspired by the Look and Feel of macOS"* [here](https://itsfoss.com/macos-like-linux-distros/) and a *"7 steps to make Linux look like macOS"* [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/steps-make-linux-look-macos/#install-gnome-extension-manager-and-tweaks), but all distros described are somewhat GNOME based, which I don't like (even thought I've been a GNOME user for more than 10 years previously).
- there is also a *"Transform Your KDE Plasma Look Like macOS"* [here](https://medium.com/@linuxscoop/transform-your-kde-plasma-look-like-macos-d30eb12349f0), however it covers almost exclusively the ***look*** *like* part, the appearing, the icons, the fonts/cursors, etc.

However, that's the part I care the least. I care mostly on the behavioral part

- the close/minimize/maximize icons being at the UL corner of windows, not UR.
- the four/three finger swipe left and right, up and down desktop gestures from MacOS, etc.

There are some articles here and there, but none focus on the part I concern, and none describe everything in one place, and they might be outdated as well. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can get the touchpad 3 and 4 finger swipe behavior using xdotool and libinput-gestures.

Follow these instructions to install libinput-gestures: https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures

And follow these to customize your gestures: https://www.lorenzobettini.it/2017/02/touchpad-gestures-in-linux-kde-with-libinput-gestures/#google_vignette

But you may get more mileage by just playing around till you get the config to your liking.

libinput gestures docs: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/gestures.html

I can't tell you how to tweak the window ui, but the gestures will go a long way toward making your box feel more mac like.

UPDATE: moving the close, minimize, and maximize buttons to the upper left instead of the upper right is quite straightforward.
Open System Settings -> Appearance -> Global Theme -> Window Decorations then select the Titlebar Buttons tab. From here you can drag the titlebar buttons to wherever you'd like them.